# how to convert string to datetime in Linq where clause

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);

var queryResultPage = (from r in CustomPlanning
                       where (r.Assignment == "In Use") && 
                             (r.CUST_SHRT_NM != null) && 
                              System.Convert.ToDateTime(r.lastlogontimestamp) < newDate && 
                             !(from uA in SurveyActivity                                                                                                                                                                  
                               where uA.CustomDemandID == r.ID
                               select uA.CustomDemandID).Contains(r.ID)
                       select r)
                       .OrderBy(t => t.ID);
```

Above is my code. lastlogontimestamp is a string field in my table. i need to do this check to show the query result in a grid. Can someone please help?

Comment: First off, be sure to always explain what is going wrong when you use your code. Second, can't you just compare `r.lastlogontimestamp < newDate`? What happens when you try that?

Comment: What's the format of the date stored in the database? Please provide sample data.

Comment: EF does not support casting from string to datetime. Why are you storing dates as a varchar in the db in the first place? It will give you other headaches in the future.

Comment: Is r.lastlogontimestamp a DateTime or a string.  Common mistake is to take a DateTime and try to convert it to a DateTime.  It doesn't work.

Comment: Good practical example why one should _think_ about how to store things in a database, and pick the correct type to store stuff.

Comment: lastlogontimestamp is a varchar field in table. this table was created long before by someoneelse and it is being used in deifferent applications. So i wont be able to modify the field.

Answer (score 1):

ok i tried this and it worked

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);

var queryResultPage = (from r in CustomPlanning
                       where (r.Assignment == "In Use") && (r.lastlogontimestamp != null && r.lastlogontimestamp != string.Empty) 
                       &&  (r.CUST_SHRT_NM != null) 
                       && !(from uA in SurveyActivity where uA.CustomDemandID == r.ID select uA.CustomDemandID).Contains(r.ID)
                       select r).OrderBy(t => t.ID).ToList();
queryResultPage = queryResultPage.Where(r => System.Convert.ToDateTime(r.lastlogontimestamp) < newDate).ToList();
```

Comment: Materializing the data into memory allows you to use LINQ To Objects which supports all of C#. Note that if `lastlogontimestamp` is in a very fixed format, you could use `DbFunctions.CreateDateTime` and build a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in this query directly. You need to materialize the results from the query in a list, and run another query to filter the returned CustomPlanning with Linq-To-Objects (it supports conversion).

You can convert newDate to string

```
string newDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString();
```

and try to compare strings instead, but you need to cover lots and lots of cases, so it is not recommended. You can consider changing the type of lastlogontimestamp to DateTime, when you have dates, it is natural to store them as dates.